# What command should I use to move these particular elements?

Tags: command-line, cp, mv

Here is my initial situation:

In a folder named for example `Father`, are stored some files in the following way: `Father` contains 24 children folders (let's call them `Child1`, `Child2`, ...), and each one of them has 2 files in it, `file1.avi` and `file1.nfo` for the first child, `file2.avi` and `file2.nfo` for the second one, etc.

What I'd like to do is to have all the `.avi` files in the `Father` folder. I don't care here about the other files being lost.

---

So far, the best I've gone is with a `cp -R ./*.avi .` but it did not extract the files from the folder and was furthermore really long to process.

How should I write it?

Comment: `mv ./*/*.avi .`.

Comment: Well that's so simple I didn't event think of this, I was stuck with my `-R`... Would you transform this as an answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The glob `*` can be used to match not only plain files, but also directories, so the command you are looking for is

```
mv ./*/*.avi .
```

Comment: Note that it won't include hidden avi files or avi files in hidden directories.

Comment: Also note that if some of the files in the current directory are symlinks to directories, it will also look for avi files in the directory they point to (in that, and the above comment, that's different from what you'd get with `find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '*.avi' -exec mv -t . {} +` (with GNU commands)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command's `-exec` option:

```
cd Father
find Child1 Child2 ... -name '*.avi' -exec mv -n {} . +
```

The command breaks down as follows:

- `find Child1 Child2 ...` will find all files and directories under Child1, Child2, etc. The default action is to print their names
- `-name '*.avi'` will limit the result to files (or directories) that match the name pattern "*.avi"
- `-exec mv {} . +` means that `find` will execute a command instead of printing the matching results; the `{}` indicates where in the command `find` should put in filenames it found, and the `+` indicates the end of the command to execute and also signals that instead of running the command once per filename, it should try to put as many filenames in as possible. For example, it might execute `mv -n Child1/as.avi Child1/many.avi Child1/matching.avi Child1/filenames.avi Child1/as.avi Child1/possible.avi .`

If you want to see what such a command *might* do, you can always write `-exec echo mv` instead of `-exec mv`

**Note 1:** The `-name '*.avi'` uses single quotes, so that the text `*.avi` is passed verbatim to the `find` command, rather than potentially expanded by the shell into filenames before it gets to the `find` command.

**Note 2:** if you have multiple filenames, under different directories, but with the same filename, the `mv` command will move all these files to the same directory, and the files with the same name will overwrite one another. You can avoid this by using the command `mv -n` (no clobber mode)